# I am getting date in this format Jul 20, 2022 6:16:29 PM from an API response in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to convert it into this format
Wed Jul 20 18:16:28 GMT+05:30 2022.
How can I achieve it using moment.js or any other suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I saw this link already, it didn't help me to get this format.

Comment: It's not meant to answer the exact format. It's best if you try to follow the solution. *If* you run into a specific issue, then come back with a [mcve].